# Работа с массивом php (foreach)

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся.

```
    public function request ()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        //return $args; Результат: 'join, 123, 123'

        foreach ($args as $element) {

            // return $element; Результат: 'join'

            switch ($element) {
                case 'join':
                    return $this->join($args);
                    break;

                default:
                    return false;
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function join()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        //return $args; Результат: 'join, 123, 123'

        foreach ($args as $element) {

            return $element; // Результат: 'join, 123, 123'

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Функция `request()` получает 3 параметра (может и больше), мы работаем с первым параметром, если он `join` то мы передаем все всходящие параметры ф-ии `request()` в ф-ю `join()`. Но что-то пошло не так и в конструкции `foreach` 
ф-ии `join()` не происходит разбиение на отдельные элементы, как было в ф-ии `request()`.

Comment: Почему в ф-ии `request ()` используется `$args = func_get_args();` а в `join()` — `$args = array(func_get_args());`?

Comment: @GrayHoax то я убрать забыл. На р-т это не влияет.

Comment: @wao138, опишите подробнее, что вы ожидаете увидеть после выполнения функции. Исходя из вашего описания код работает корректно: http://ideone.com/s0otN2

Comment: @VenZell, в `return $element; // Результат: 'join, 123, 123'`(ф-я join () ) по идее должен был вернуться только 1ый элемент, как в ф-ии `request ()`

Comment: Написал ответ. Если автор сформулирует свою задачу яснее... будет лучше)

Comment: Проще всего делегировать вызов со всеми аргументами используя функцию __call_user_func_array()__. Пример использования в контексте вопроса можно глянуть в моем ответе ниже.

Answer (score 1):

После обсуждения с автором вопроса, родилось понимание задачи, но при этом пришлось "додумать":) основываясь на названии функции. Если необходимо вывести строку слияния при работе функции join, то код должен быть следующим:

```
    public function request ()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        //return $args; Результат: 'join, 123, 123'

        foreach ($args as $element) {

            // return $element; Результат: 'join'

            switch ($element) {
                case 'join':
                    return $this->join(array_slice($args, 1));
                    break;

                default:
                    return false;
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function join()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();

        //return $args; Результат: 'join, 123, 123'

        return implode(' ', $args);

    }
}
```

Но сразу оговорюсь, что эта раелизщация - с наименьшими правками кода автора. Я бы его переписал в корне...

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, автор вопроса сам себя запутал.

В методе `join` он ожидает `$args` такого вида (как в методе `request`):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "join"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

А получает такого:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "join"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "123"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
}
```

Учитывая это, `return` внутри `foreach` отрабатывает абсолютно корректно и возвращает первый и единственный элемент массива `$args`, который в свою очередь тоже является массивом.

Как же так получилось?

`return $this->join($args);`

Здесь автор думает, что снова передает то же количество аргументов, что и пришло в `request`, а на самом деле передает **единственным аргументом** в метод `join` **массив**, содержащий эти первоначальные аргументы.

Answer (score 0):

> ... мы передаем все всходящие параметры ф-ии request() в ф-ю join()

Пожалуйста:

```
// в контексте объекта:
call_user_func_array([$this, 'join'], $args);

// в статическом контексте:
// 1.
call_user_func_array([MyAwasomeJoiner::class, 'join'], $args);

// 2.
call_user_func_array('MyAwasomeJoiner::join', $args);

// в глобальном контексте
call_user_func_array('join', $args);
```